# how to discover serialVersionUID of serialized objects

Tags: java, serialization

Short question: how to discover the serialVersionUID of Objects that are in serialized form.

Detail:  I have some serialized versions of Objects in a session database for a web application.  For some of these objects, I failed to specify a serialVersionUID in the source code so the JVM created one for me.  I want to discover what the serialVersionUID of the saved Objects are so that I can hard code it in my source files.

I have easy access to read the serialized data.  I've already gone through and deleted the (old) sessions that won't read with the current versions of my code, so I know that every serialized object matches the current codebase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out the serialVersionUID of a serialized Java object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703591/how-can-i-find-out-the-serialversionuid-of-a-serialized-java-object)

Comment: The answers there deal more with generating the serialVersionUID from the source/class files.  I want to discover the serialVersionUID in existing serialized objects.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the data, you can simply look at the eight octets following the class name in the stream as indicated by the [grammar for Java Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258)

```
00000000: aced 0005 7372 0003 466f 6f00 0000 0000  ....sr..Foo.....
00000010: 0000 0102 0001 4c00 066d 794e 616d 6574  ......L..myNamet
00000020: 0012 4c6a 6176 612f 6c61 6e67 2f53 7472  ..Ljava/lang/Str
00000030: 696e 673b 7870 7400 044a 6f68 6e         ing;xpt..John
```

The name of the class above is "Foo" (no package), and the serialVersionUID is 1L.  Here's another example:

```
00000000: aced 0005 7372 0011 7374 6163 6b6f 7665  ....sr..stackove
00000010: 7266 6c6f 772e 466f 6fff ffff ffff 7e3c  rflow.Foo.....~<
00000020: 1802 0001 4c00 066d 794e 616d 6574 0012  ....L..myNamet..
00000030: 4c6a 6176 612f 6c61 6e67 2f53 7472 696e  Ljava/lang/Strin
00000040: 673b 7870 7400 044a 6f68 6e              g;xpt..John
```

The classname is stackoverflow.Foo.  The serialVersionUID is 0xff7e3c18 as noted by this sequence of octets:

```
ff ffff fffff 7e3c 18
```

Now all you have to do is look at the file format to find out where your object is in each case and read the *serialVersionUID* that immediately follows the *className* in the grammar linked above.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to use ObjectStreamClass.lookup(class).

I run a method that de-serializes all of the session objects in my database.  Then I run ObjectStreamClass.lookup() on each class that I am interested in.  It gives me a ObjectStreamClass object for the class.  A ObjectStreamClass object contains the class name and the serialVersionUID.

I'll take the output of that and modify my source files accordingly.

Comment: Is the code for the classes still the same as it was for the all of the serialized instances in your database?

Comment: If the class actually changed, then the ObjectStreamClass.lookup() can throw `java.io.InvalidClassException`  if the class actually changed.  If it's not changed, then there's no point in doing any of this; just use `serialver package.Class`. How are you getting the class to pass to `lookup()`?

Comment: ObjectStreamClass.lookup() worked fine for me.  To get the list of classes I just massaged a list of filenames from the package that I know has the code w/o the explicit serialVersionUID.

Comment: Yes, that will work if you have the source code (or old compiled classes.)